# When I load the files in my server the session does not persist

Tags: php, session

In my local server the site run fine but when I load the files in godaddy the searcher and the login do not work. I'd tried changing the session save path in the php.ini file, changing the permissions and nothing works.

Comment: You need to show us the code that doesn't work. We have no idea what it's doing. For example, do you have `session_start()` on every page you use sessions?

Comment: need to see codes that include the codes which starts session.

Comment: Maybe output (php warning message) is causing the session to not get set as headers already sent. Though could be many things.

Comment: if($totalRows_R_busco_profesional>0){
    
 $resultados_busco_profesional = array();
 do {
  $resultados_busco_profesional[] = array("id" => $row_R_busco_profesional['id'],
"nombre"  => $row_R_busco_profesional['nombre'],
"apellido"  => $row_R_busco_profesional['apellido'];
 } while ($row_R_busco_profesional = mysql_fetch_assoc($R_busco_profesional));
    
 }
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['resultados_busco_profesional'] = $resultados_busco_profesional;
   header("Location:../../profesionales/?extra-filters=yes&espfilter=".$especialidad);
}